# Cannot open MS word, PDF on Fuse based file system

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, fuse

I am trying to implement Fuse Based file system using Node.js on Mac. I am using fuse-native (https://github.com/fuse-friends/fuse-native) for mounting a file system.

I have a directory on my local file system that I want to mirror with the mounted file system. So if I save file on mounted file system, it should save to the mirrored directory and if I download file in mirrored directory, I should be able to open it on mounted directory.

I have implemented all the basic fuse callbacks like read, readdir, write, getattr, chmod, chown, mknod, mkdir, rmdir

So far, I am able to create, update, delete, save text file to mounted file system. When I try to open any MS word, pdf or pages file from the mounted file system (that's present on mirrored directory), it gives me

```
Word found unreadable content in file.docx. Do you want to recover the contents of this document? If you trust the source of this document, click Yes.
```

and when I click recover, it is successfully able to recover it.

I am not sure what's going on but not able to open the word file.

My read function looks like (I am reading and opening from mirrored directory):
fs is the node file system

```
fs.read(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, null, (err, bytesRead, buffer) => {
      if (err) {
        Logger.info(err.message);
        return cb(Fuse.ENOENT);
      }
      const part = buffer.slice(position, position + bytesRead);
      part.copy(buffer);
      return cb(bytesRead);
    });
```

and open:

```
const open = (path: string, flags: number, cb: Function) => {
  // Logger.info('In Open');
  try {
    const fd = fs.openSync(
      `/Users/xyz/Desktop/Fuse${path}`,
      toFlag(flags)
    );
    return cb(0, fd);
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.info(err.message);
    return cb(Fuse.ENOENT);
  }
};
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by changing the read function. Read was wrong.

```
try {
      const bytesRead = fs.readSync(fd, buf, 0, length, position);
      return cb(bytesRead);
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.info(error.message);
      return cb(Fuse.ENOENT);
    }
```